# Is there any way to open a new window in terminal using root?

Tags: root, linux-terminal

I'm using bash shell in Linux and I wonder if there is any way to open a new terminal window when I log in as root using  `su` or `sudo su`.

What I mean is if it's possible to type sudo su and open a new terminal window with root prompt (make a kind of command for every time I type `sudo su` a new window opens with root prompt).

Comment: Type the name of the terminal emulator your DE uses and hit enter. I think `terminal` should work for Xfce. Of don't become sudo with `sudo su` and just run `sudo terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make a kind of command for every time I type sudo su a new window opens with root prompt

You can use **alias** command to do the job for you. If I want a new window with root privileges whenever I type **sudo-su** in terminal, I will issue this alias command :

`alias 'sudo-su'='sudo terminal_program_name'`

where *terminal_program_name* is the program you use to access bash shell *viz.* konsole, gnome-terminal, deepin-terminal, etc.

**Note**: **Alias is temporary and will be lost** once you close the active window from where you issued the alias command. To make your alias persistent, edit your `.bashrc` file and append the aforementioned alias command in it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `tmux`. I work with it on daily basis: on my laptop, router and server at work; in windowed terminal, text mode, via ssh. With its keyboard shortcuts it gave me significant performance boost. For me there is no turning back to separate terminal windows.

Comment: +1 tmux is so good. With high resolution you can handle 4~6 terminal in a single window. SSH server, roots, logs watching, processus watching etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Ubuntu or some other OS that is similar. Normally you can do CTRL + SHIFT + T to open a new terminal. It should launch that terminal as the currently logged in user (whoami)

Comment: I'm using Manjaro with Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), you can do that. If not, you can't do that.

**First** - Open two terminal.

**Second** - Type `su` on the first terminal and type your root password.

Comment: For second question, answer is no.
Because when you type sudo su. You just login to root current terminal session. You are still same user on desktop environment. You have to switch to another user for different terminal

Comment: And I can't associate 'sudo su' to a command to open a new window?

Comment: Ah okay new idea come to my mind.
You can give command option like `sudo su` which is run initally when you open terminal.

Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Run Custom Command ...